# $2$-Sylow and $3$-Sylow subgroup of external direct product $S_4\times S_3$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

$S_4\times S_3$ is a group of order $144$.

$2$--Sylow subgroup is of order 16 and $3$--Sylow subgroup is of order $9$.

Is there any way to find whether these subgroups are normal or not ?

In general, If $H$ is a a subgroup of $G$, to prove $H$ is not normal, we need to find an element $a$ $\in$ $G$ such that $aH$ $\neq$ $Ha$. This is the only way I know to prove it is not normal.

We know that by Sylow's $3^\text{rd}$ theorem, the number of subgroups of order $16$ can be $1$,$3$ or $9$. I came across the statement $\textbf{“$2$-Sylow subgroup is isomorphic to $D_4 \times Z_2$}$ $\textbf{and hence number of $2$--Sylow subgroups are 9}$ $\textbf{and hence it is not normal.''}$ I am clueless how that isomorphism can be found and about the conclusion of number of $2$-Sylow subgroups are $9$!! If i am sure about that, then   by "A Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if it is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$". I can say all those subgroups are not normal.

Please let me know what topic's knowledge in group theory I am lacking to understand that. Please suggest me if any source available to learn that topic. Thank you “

Comment: Can you write down any subgroups of $S_4 \times S_3$ of order 16?  (For example, a subgroup of the form $H_1 \times H_2$, where $H_1 < S_4$ and $H_2 < S_3$?)  If you can find more than one of them, then you have proved that each one is non-normal.

Comment: Don't use MathJax to typeset normal text. In this particular case it goes off the text area and the end is unreadable.

Comment: Little detail: Sylow, not sylow (it is the name of a mathematician).

Comment: Note that proper notation in MathJax and LaTeX is $S_4\times S_3<$ not $\textbf{$S_4$ x $S_3$}.$ I edited accordingly.  $\qquad$

Comment: To have a subgroup of order $16$, subgroups of $S_4$ and $S_3$ can be of order $8$ and order $2$ respectively. $D_4$ is one of the subgroup of order $8$ and $Z_2$ is one of the subgroup of order $2$. So, $D_4 \times Z_2$ is a subgroup of order $16$. And there are $3$ different subgroups of order $8$ in $S_4$ and there are $3$ different subgroups of order $2$ in $S_3$ and hence we get $9$ subgroups of order $16$. Let me know if any mistake. Thank you  @RaviFernando